# If my default python encoder and system is UTF-8, how Im getting this error-UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u0447'

Tags: python, jenkins, unicode

Getting below error when I execute a python code from `jenkins`-

> ```
> File "/export/app-33-1/jenkins/w/ee4a092a/install/src/linux-amd64-gcc_4_4-release/bin/eat2/eat.py", line 553, in _runtest
> print('ERROR:' + msg)
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u0447' in position 315: 
> ordinal not in range(128)
> ```

From where exactly it takes encoder - ascii as I have changed default encoding of python, `jenkins` master and slave process as well as systems.

Even added `# coding: utf-8` at the start of script but didn't work.

Its not about only printing the string in console, my code tries to access some files and file path contains some Russian characters so everything fails.

When I run the same script manually from linux console, everything works.

Any idea what could be the solution here?

Comment: What version of Python is this, and where does `msg` come from?

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to wide-spread belief, the default encoding for the built-in `open()` function as well as the `sys.std*` streams (`print()` uses `sys.stdout`) **is not always UTF-8** in Python 3. It might be on one machine, but not the other, because it's platform-dependent.

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout) for `sys.stdin/stdout/stderr`:

> These streams are regular text files like those returned by the open() function. Their parameters are chosen as follows:
>
> - The character encoding is platform-dependent. Non-Windows platforms use the locale encoding [...]

And later on:

> Under all platforms, you can override the character encoding by setting the PYTHONIOENCODING environment variable before starting Python [...]

Note that there are some exceptions for Windows.

For files opened with `open`, you can easily get control by explicitly setting the `encoding=` parameter.